# Umbraco 7.4 URL Redirect Feature

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there an available URL redirect for Umbraco 7.4? I mean I'm aware that there is a URL Redirect Management Tools in Umbraco 7.5 but we are using the lower version and it doesn't have that. Is there a way to achieve the same result? The scenario is this.

1. We created an `web.com/about-us` page. Now this is cached in google search now.
2. We then decided to change `about-us` to `corporate` now the cached version is still pointing to `about-us` where in fact the new URL now is `web.com/corporate`

How can I achieve a URL redirect? If someone manually typed or clicked on the cached url like `about-us` how can Umbraco 7.4 redirects it to the correct site? Would appreciate a step by step process if possible since I'm still new in Umbraco

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like SEO Checker to manage this for you - there are also other plugins available that can do the redirection management.

https://our.umbraco.com/packages/website-utilities/seo-checker

Answer (score 0):

As my first post has been hidden due to lack of detail, which is understandable, I am adding this new answer with more details.

We use [UrlTracker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UrlTracker/) for our projects - it is a nuget package that you install and then you can start using it. This can help.

The Url Tracker is used to manage URLs within umbraco and it automatically tracks URL changes, for instance when a node is renamed, this makes sure the old URL will redirect to the new location. Using this; you can also create your own redirects, based on a simple URL or using a Regex pattern. This is especially handy while migrating existing indexed URLs to your new website.

Please check [this umbraco package web page](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/developer-tools/301-url-tracker) for more details. Alternative links can be found below, hope this helps.

https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2013/sharing-is-caring/
https://www.marceldigital.com/blog/2017/08/5-umbraco-seo-packages-you-need-right-now